# What Wordpress plugin is this one?

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble identifying a plugin (or perhaps is not even a plugin), but can you tell me what plugin outputs the section at the bottom of the post that has the headers: "Did you like this article?" and "Related Posts", and has a list of bookmarking links, and a list of posts respectively.

Image of the stuff I'm referring to: [image]

Example URL: http://www.escapefromcorporate.com/networking-tools-and-help-upmo/

**Edit:**

Thanks for "Related Posts" plugin references. Now, for the other one (Did you like this article?), it is a really mysterious plugin. :)   I'm thinking it is in fact a plugin since you can see other websites with almost the exact same options at:

http://www.joshsundquist.com/blog/2010/04/17/recording-my-audiobook/

http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2010/05/01/credit-card-concierge/

http://www.brinkzone.com/exercise-performance/alternating-dumbell-rows-to-hit-your-back-and-core/

http://www.motivationtomove.com/blog/comments/totally_awesome_fly_out_to_cedar_key_florida_2_2/

Any hints? :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [Yet Another Related Post Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/) and as for the sharing one that could be a number of things. A lot of third party sites, like [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) and [ShareThis](http://www.sharethis.com/) provide these social media widgets. They make plugins for WordPress and give you the option to implement raw code for their widgets and are fully customizable via CSS.

AddThis and ShareThis both provide tracking analytics as well. That's always a plus.

If you don't want to use AddThis or SharThis, try this top rated [Sociable](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sociable/) plugin on WordPress' Plugin directory.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer!  I'm pretty sure the other plugin is not AddThis, or ShareThis. I've spent a few hours already trying to find that mysterious plugin (perhaps I missed something). I've updated my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I just went to the page in your screen shot, viewed it's source, and it is indeed ShareThis. Like I said in my answer, you can fully customize AddThis or ShareThis to look and feel any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

[SexyBookmarks](http://www.sexybookmarks.net/) is another popular plugin with similar functionality

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do related posts. It requires a bit of overhead on the admin side, but pays off in performance increase down the road. Try [efficient related posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/efficient-related-posts/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it made me think more carefully about what "Related posts" plugin should I use.

Answer (score 1):

The "Did you like this article" section seems to be a set element of the theme, *not* a plug-in.  Many of the other sites you listed use the same or similar themes as those available from [Jestro](http://jestro.com/portfolio/) and [Theme Foundry](http://thethemefoundry.com/wordpress/).  I think you're looking at a built-in function, not something easily portable without purchasing one of the themes or looking at the PHP code.

However, you could build the same thing with a text widget ... just place your own social bookmark codes in place of the ones you see on other sites.

Comment: Yeah, I finally realized that. xD I'm going to have to build it by myself which is not that hard. Thanks for the pointers.